# How to get all the possible sequences of x characters from a string of n characters in java

Tags: java, string, character, combinations

I am playing with Java and my problem is the following:

I have a string of n characters, e.g. abcd, how can i get all the possible sequences of x characters in this string? with "sequences" i mean that I am interested ONLY in those combinations that respect the order of the characters in the original string.

So for instance if I am looking for 2 characters sequences in the string abcd I would like to obtain only

ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd.

I am not interested in all the other possible combinations (such as da, cb etc), because they do not respect the order of the characters in the original string.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried so far? As a suggestion: put a little bit of your code into your question which shows you've done *something* to start solving the problem. There's some fairly simple cases you should be able to handle: a zero length string, a string containing a single character, a string containing two characters. And then, how would you go about getting sequences of a single character from a multi-character string.

Comment: The problem is not how to handle specific cases (a series of nested loops would be enough), but rather how to handle the problem dynamically, i.e. how to obtain x-characters sequences from n-characters strings.
And for that, i have to admit I have no code to suggest so far..

Comment: Isn't the first character of every sequence you want to return a single character from the string? Do you have code that at least gets you the first character of every sequence? Once you have the first character of the sequence, isn't the next problem getting the next character of the sequence? And isn't that really just the same problem again... with a shorter string? (I suspect that the answers that you get to this question are going to be the code that you can already do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [combination without repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) problem.
There are plenty of implementations around the Internet, you can find one in [this class](https://github.com/hmkcode/Java/blob/master/java-combinations/Combination.java/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solvable with two loops. What have you done so far to solve it on your own?

```
    public static void print(String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
           char curChar = str.charAt(i);
           for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++) {
                char otherChar = str.charAt(j);
                System.out.println(new String(new char[] { curChar, otherChar }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: as i said, the problem is not solving specific cases, but having a solution that can dynamically deal with sequences of n characters, not just sequences of 2 characters as in the example and in your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
final String placeHolder = "ignore me 'cause toElement parameter of subSet() is exclusive";
    set.add("a");
    set.add("b");
    set.add("c");
    set.add("d");
    set.add(placeHolder);
    for (String ch : set) {
        Set<String> subSet = set.subSet(ch, placeHolder);
        if (subSet.size() > 1) {
            for (String subCh : subSet) {
                if (!ch.equals(subCh)) {
                    System.out.println(ch + subCh);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```